# onscroll not adding class - issue

Tags: javascript, onscroll

I am trying to create `onscroll` effect using Javascript but I have some problems. I have 2 classes: The first one, `.phorography_box`, is active; the second one, `.photography_box_active`, is not active.

What I would like is to when I scroll down with my mouse around `1000px` to add the second class which is `.photography_box_active`.

Here is my JS code:

```
var photoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("photography_box");

window.onscroll = function() {
    loopBox()
};
function loopBox(){
    if ( window > 500 ){
        for ( f = 0; f <= photoBox.length -1; f++ ) {
            photoBox[f].classList.add("photography_box_active");
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: `window > 500` will always return `false` here. Code inside will not be executed. *edited* `if (window.pageYOffset > 500) { ... }`

Comment: you need to use window.pageYOffset to get scroll position

Comment: Thanks that solve the problem